# How would i go about adding a button to let images load in

Tags: html

I would like to add a button that lets the user load in my gallery, but not with a link I have the actual image file.

Here is what I have right now:

```
<doctype HTML>

<body>

<h1>
Jadon James Photography™
</h1>

<p1>
Hi! My name is Jadon and I am an amature photographer based in Arizona. 
</p1>

<br>
<br>
<br>

Click the "See Photos" button to view my gallery. 

<body style="background-color:#21C1D0;"> </body>

</body>

</doctype HTML>
```

Comment: If you want to have a simple solution, [here's an image gallery from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_gallery.asp) that you can use. Also you might want to think about using a website builder (Wix, SquareSpace, Weebly) for that kind of website. It would simplify the process greatly, while achieving a professional look.

Comment: @XBOSSNATIION do yo want upload an image to your view from your pc?

Comment: So, I am building my website, for photography purposes, and this will be my site... obviously I took the pictures so I have the .jpg and .raw files, but I want to upload those onto my site that I am writing the HTML for, in addition I don’t want those pictures to show until I press the “show gallery” button so I’m wondering how to make that button, and how to get it to show my pictures..